# Can we run magento without doing indexing (for any index) we have large catalog size around (2M)

Tags: magento-1.8

We want to use magento store without doing indexing.

Is this possible. Actually issue is that our magento CE is taking much more time in doing re-indexing.

Please suggest on same.

Answer (score 2):

- Magento Re-indexing is required to improve the performance of your web
  store and to update front-end store if any data changes occur.
- For example, suppose you change the price of an item from $4.99 to $3.99. Magento must re-index the price change to display it on your web store.
- Without indexing, Magento would have to calculate the price of every product on the fly—taking into account shopping cart price rules, bundle pricing, discounts, tier pricing, and so on. Loading the price for a product would take a long time, possibly resulting in cart abandonment.

---

- *So, if you are doing any changes in your catalog, it would be better
  to continue with Re-indexing. By, doing re-indexing, you're actually
  improving prformence and saving time in your front-end.*

Comment: Thanks for your response.yes this is point of thinking.